# Is it possible to add row data via a callback to tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I need a table that shows about 2.5 million rows from an array that is already created in memory. When I create the table and add the array to the 'data' property, the browser engine runs out of memory after some (significant) time. I assume that tabulator not only creates objects for the current virtual DOM part, but for each entry in the array in advance.

So my question: is it possible to not provide the entire array, but only the the count of rows, and let tabulator ask for the content of each row via a callback only when needed for rendering. Of course it only makes sense if tabulator does not keep any data of rows that are gone out of view.

I know that this might be in conflict with some column calculation features or others, but this would be fine for my use case.

The same use case is working with canvas-datagrid, which I have tried before.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Ajax to get the data there is the Progressive Ajax Loading that will help you to load data using the pagination module to make a series of requests for part of the data set, one at a time, appending it to the table as the data arrives.
Doc is here: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.3/data#ajax-alter

Comment: thank you Zoe. The app to create is ment for desktop and hosted by electron. So implementing ajax loading will be a little work, but I will try. But id would not help if tabulator keeps all data in memory when received. If the user scolls once from top to bottom, we will be at the same point as if we laoded all records to the data - property.It only makes sense if tabulator deletes records when they are out of view ad re-requests them when needed again. Do you know anything about that behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Progressive loading is an option, but you still are going to run into the issue that you will have two copies of the data in memory. It will either happen automatically if in 'load' mode or manually in 'scroll' mode as you scroll through the table. The best option would seem to be to have code via say a button that loads the data using either `setData()` or `replaceData()`. Then the user could fetch either the next or previous set of data in batches.